# Add to Array Merge

Tags: php

I have a function which blacklists all `public_query_vars` and `private_query_vars`.

But `wp-admin` and `wp-login` aren't listed in these arrays. Is there a way to add them to these lists?

Original code:

```
    public function forbidden_slugs() {
        $wp = new WP;
        return array_merge( $wp->public_query_vars, $wp->private_query_vars );
    }
```

Something I tried but didn't work:

```
    public function forbidden_slugs() {
        $wp = new WP;
        return array_merge( $wp->public_query_vars, $wp->private_query_vars, 'wp-admin', 'wp-login' );
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: `array_merge` merges __arrays__. `'wp-admin'` is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
return array_merge( $wp->public_query_vars, $wp->private_query_vars, array('wp-admin', 'wp-login') );
```

You are using [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) that require array's as a parameter but you supply strings into it.

Comment: I have tried your code but it seems to completely ignore the line now

Comment: i initially ommited return, maybe you have to add it in there

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! I said that right after I posted that comment. I will accept your answer when I'm allowed to.